# Razor Session Data - HttpContextAccessor is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a MVC5 newbie,  creating a test web Site  to look at MVC5 and Razor

I have a very simple site after user logs on and I need to change menus via _Layout  from "Login" to add "Logout" "Account".

Note: The site is has its own authentication,  I will look at single login later.

I am really struggling with managing session data in MVC5, not sure which is the best approach. I have tried TEMP DATA , but although I peak I have found that after user has been redirected between a couple of pages the data is lost. So looked at good old cookie, but since GDPR  I can tell there is a lot less default support for cookies out of the box.

Anyway in the Startup I believe I am doing all the right things

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                                   options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });   
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();  
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set session timeout value
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });
        }


services.AddMvc();
services.AddCaching(); 
services.AddSession();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

dependency inject it in , but in the Post when I attempt to call the  SetString  , the "private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;" is null

Oddly the _Layout is not throwing same null exception

```
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
   @inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

   @{
        string UserId = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");
   }
```

After working on ASP.Net , the simple approach to handling  Session , beginning to question whether I have missed something as it seems a lot of work in MVC5. So should I  be using a different approach in MVC5

Comment: Do you have services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>(); also?

Comment: I have tried it with services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); and with services.AddSignleton<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>()

Comment: I have both:  services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); and          services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>(); I appears to work in my solution

Comment: Your code is not MVC 5. It is ASP.NET MVC Core. and it's definitely not Razor Pages.

Comment: HttpContextAccessor should not be scoped.  it's a singleton.  It should be registered with AddHttpContextAccessor which adds it as a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
```

this to true i.e

```
options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
```

and your session will not be null anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add this this for anyone else , probably not the cleanest code
With help form Sanjay now got a crude site up and running

Startup class , example code

public class Startup
    {

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

}

Code for .csHtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@{
    if (Context.Session.GetString("UserRole") != null)
    {
```

code for .cs

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
    public LoginModel(ISiteUserService siteUserService, 
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;        
    }
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {

        if(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserRole")!= null)
        {
```